# push_back const char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector, constants

I'm trying to push back a `const char*` in a vector in a forloop. `char_temp` is a struct called `segment`, and `chars_temp` is a vector of structs. See my code below:

```
for (int bg = 0; bg < str.size(); bg++) {
    string sym(1, str[bg]);
    const char* bg_cc;
    bg_cc = sym.c_str();

    char_temp.symbol_first = bg_cc;
    char_temp.symbol_second = "*";

    chars_temp.push_back(char_temp);
}
```

The problem is that the push backed char is a pointer, so the `char_temp.symbol_first` consists of the same address. The struct needs a `const char*` for `char_temp.symbol_first`, so how can I fill this vector with different addresses within the forloop?

I tried `const char* bg_cc = new char` in the forloop, but `bg_cc` keeps having the same address.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried const char* bg_cc = new char in the forloop, but bg_cc keeps having the same address.

That's fine, it's somewhat expected. What's important is that it *points* to different addresses.

You need to use `char* bg_cc = new char` and then `strcpy` from `sym.c_str()` to create a copy, not just assign the pointer to `sym.c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

1) The sym object would be destroyed after each "for" iteration. And `bg_cc` and `char_temp.symbol_first` pointers become invalid. You need to allocate memory in each "for" iteration for `bg_cc` pointer. Possible with `new` operator. Are you sure you need `const char*` here? May be single `char` will be enough?

2) It looks you put the same object in `chars_temp` container. You need to allocate memory for `char_temp` object in each loop iteration.